# assign a property to a many to many relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I'm making a couple of models for cooking, in django, Recipes and Ingredients.
I use a many to many field to relate both. Now, I'd like to assign a number to each relationship, so going from

`recipe.ingredients = [sugar,egg]`

to

`recipe.ingredients = {sugar:200,egg:2}`

How can I do that? It is 100% necessary to explicitly build a third model ingredients_recipes? The table should exist already, but I want to know if is possible to use the many to many field directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to create the intermediate model with your additional fields. You can then specify the intermediate in [a `through` argument to the `ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), for example:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    #...
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredients, through="RecipeIngredients")

class RecipeIngredients(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('recipe', 'ingredient')
```

See also the official documentation: [Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)